# Silverlight 3 oob window border

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser

I was wondering if I can customise the look and feel of the OOB window of my SL app? I want it to look different than the standard windows frame (maybe at least change the visible buttons like minimise or maximise...)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only change the Window's Height, Width, and Title. You can't modify the window chrome.

- [Window Settings on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowsettings_members(VS.95).aspx)
- One of many blog entries [pointing out that there's no windows chrome customization](http://www.cynergysystems.com/blogs/page/michaelwolf?entry=silverlight_out_of_browser_deep)

This feature is showing up as a [common feature request for Silverlight 4](http://silverlight.net/forums/p/102856/234574.aspx), though.

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 4, you can choose to remove the window chrome for OOB applications and produce controls to trigger your own window moving/resizing/minimizing/maximizing functionality.

http://blogs.msdn.com/olivers/archive/2010/03/15/silverlight-4-out-of-browser-enhancements.aspx